# How to find the 'relative' position of an element to its parent element? Or: How to find Mr. Blue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have basically 2 div elements. The first is a scrolling container and the second one is an element that is placed in the container. I would like to find the y-position relative to the scrolling container. I wrapped all of it into a piece of example-code titled *How to find Mr. Blue?*

```
<div style="height:100px; border:solid 1px black; overflow-y:scroll;">
    Please scroll down...
    <br/>
    <div style="height:400px;">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="MrBlue" style="height:20px; background-color:blue; color:white">
        Mr. Blue
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would like a **JavaScript / jQuery statement** that alerts the **vertical-position** of the **Mr. Blue. div** *relative* to the scrolling container.

Ps. If you would like to 'fiddle' with mr. Blue, check http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/Qjr5q/.

Comment: care to bring Mr Blue to jsfiddle so we could all party with him?

Comment: Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/Qjr5q/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you can add css `position: relative` to the wrapping/scrolling container then it's as simple as

```
document.getElementById('MrBlue').offsetTop
```

and jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/eU3pN/2/

Comment: Ooo, it's not JQuery though is it ;) $(#MrBlue).position.top() - Write less, do more ;)

Comment: write less, do more - true - but takes more time and cpu power - sometimes you can't afford that - especially if you'd test your jquery heavy websites on older PCs/laptops or netbooks you'd realize that jquery isn't nowhere near when it comes to speed when compared to native JS. It simply have to handle both optimal and worst case scenarios which make it slower in every possible case. And although it's my fav tool for quick prototyping I'm always trying to put as much native code as I can if I know performance on older setups/browsers will benefit from that.

Comment: I see your point - I suppose the JQuery source files will translate `$(#MrBlue).position.top()` into `document.getElementById('MrBlue').offsetTop` or something similar anyway

Comment: It looks like the .offsetTop performs good. The problem has to do with scrolling. Check the example and read Mr. Blue when you scroll and when you don't scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/Qjr5q/. Your answer works and jQuery returns a different thing.

Comment: Ah forgot to add that if you'd want to get its position inside the scrollable element you'd need to subtract the scrollTop property of its parentNode - check this jsfiddle fix http://jsfiddle.net/Qjr5q/12/

Answer (score 3):

you can use [jQuery position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#MrBlue").position().top);
});
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixsigl/F8eFu/)

**Update:** Container must have `position:relative;` otherwise it wont work

see this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixsigl/pUcsd/)

Comment: This doesn't work. If you add some enters before the outer div, you'll get a different result.

Comment: Perfect... works perfectly. Mr. Blue is grateful to you! Can you include this in your answer (for future generations)?

Comment: Sorry... but after careful consideration the answer needs to be the .offsetTop. The problem has to do with scrolling. Check the example and read Mr. Blue when you scroll and when you don't scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/Qjr5q/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's .position()

> The .position() method allows us to
>   retrieve the current position of an
>   element relative to the offset parent.
>   Contrast this with .offset(), which
>   retrieves the current position
>   relative to the document. When
>   positioning a new element near another
>   one and within the same containing DOM
>   element, .position() is the more
>   useful.
>
> Returns an object containing the
>   properties top and left.

http://jqapi.com/#p=position

Comment: Can you add some code to jsFiddle to show how your answer would work: jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/Qjr5q

Comment: The thing your were missing in the example was that the scroll container needed to be relative.

Comment: i see that. haven't explored it much.